# Jquery modal dialog box with iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, modal-dialog

Hey! I have a problem with modal dialog box with iframe in it.
Here is this code, what I'm using: http://pastebin.com/VJNqvs3L 
Everything seems right till place, where I want to get rel atribute from that anchor tag.
Could anyone please check this code, how to get right rel from each anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, you should use

```
var data = $(this).attr("rel");
```

This will make sure that you get the correct "rel" attribute from the anchor tag that was clicked on.